# Empty page when generating sunburst chart

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram, plotly.graph-objects

I was trying to write a function to generate sunburst chart, but the figure shows a blank page. There are no error message. Then I was testing with simple sample data (see below) but it is still blank. When I use plotly.express instead plotly.graph_objects then it works. Anyone know why? Thanks for the help!

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
# Sample data
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'Subcategory': ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a basic sunburst chart
fig = go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=df['Subcategory'],
    parents=df['Category'],
    values=df['Value']
))

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))

# Save the chart to an HTML file
fig.write_html('basic_hierarchical_sunburst_chart.html')
```

```
# using plotly.express then it works
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Sample data
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'Subcategory': ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a sunburst chart using Plotly Express
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['Category', 'Subcategory'], values='Value')

# Show the chart
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example data is not a valid sunburst graph. `labels` should be a list of all unique elements and `parents` must contain entries from `labels` or an empty string if an element has no parent. You define the elements `['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2']` but then assign A and B (which you did not define as elements) as parent elements.

By changing your example data to

```py
data = {
    'Category': ['','A', 'A','', 'B', 'B'],
    'Subcategory': ['A','A1', 'A2','B', 'B1', 'B2'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20]
}
```

I get the graph

[image]

I am not sure what you mean with "When I use plotly.express instead plotly.graph_objects then it works." Can you provide the full code for that? With your data, `plotly.express` also leads to a blank page for me.

Comment: Thanks! it works! I've added the code for plotly.express, which works for me.

Comment: Ok, your plotly.express code is not the equivalent code to your plotly.graph_objects code. The definition via path (plotly.express) is different from that via labels and parents (plotly.express or plotly.graph_objects). You can also use the definition with labels and parents with plotly.express and with your data, you run into the same issue.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask another question? Is it possible for `go.figure` to plot non-unique children labels in different layers/ hierarchy? like `parents=['y','y', 'y', 'x3', 'x3', 'x3'], children=['x1','x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x2', 'x5']`